# Invalid MySQL Query when passing in value from external select box

Tags: php, mysql

I have two files in use. The first is a front end select box with a list of dynamically populated char/text values that uses POST to send the selected value to a back end file. This back end file assigns this value to a variable and that variable is then used in the following query:

```
    $query = "SELECT DoctorName, Speciality FROM hospital WHERE HospitalName =".$hosname;
```

However, I keep getting the Invalid Query message I have set in my or die(); and I have no idea why. The full section of php code on the backend file is as follows:

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("No connection");
    mysqli_select_db($conn, "hospitaldb") or die("db will not open");

    $hosname=$_POST['valuelist'];
    $query = "SELECT DoctorName, Speciality FROM hospital WHERE HospitalName =".$hosname;

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>mDoctorName</th><th>Speciality</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td>" . $row[1] . "</td></tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Note: I have checked that the value from the select box is being passed in using print and it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*I am only testing this locally but thanks to all who recommended mysql_real_escape_string() to protect against injections.*

Comment: Try adding `mysql_error()` in the die message.  Let's see what error is being thrown.

Comment: Have you tried the exact same query from the mysql command line client?

Comment: take a look what is `sql injection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting SQL query you want would be something like;

```
SELECT DoctorName, Speciality FROM hospital WHERE HospitalName = 'MyHospital'
```

In other words, you need to add quotes to your query creation;

```
$query = "SELECT DoctorName, Speciality FROM hospital WHERE HospitalName = '".$hosname."'";
```

You should really also escape the hospital name using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before just inserting it into a query.

Comment: Ah wow, such a foolish mistake to make. Thanks for the heads up on the mysql_real_escape_string() too.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're not wrapping the value in quotes, so the query is malformed.  My PHP is rusty, excuse me if there is a syntax error in my example, below:

```
 $query = "SELECT DoctorName, Speciality FROM hospital WHERE HospitalName ='".$hosname ."';";
```

However, the string concatenation leaves you open to SQL Injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Consider using prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your error is you need to surround your variable in single quotes like:

```
$query = "SELECT DoctorName, Speciality FROM hospital WHERE HospitalName ='".$hosname."'";
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming $hosname is a string. Your query is failing because you haven't quoted it.

```
$query = "SELECT DoctorName, Speciality FROM hospital 
   WHERE HospitalName = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($hosname) . "'";
```

Note I added `mysql_real_escape_string` as well as the quotes to protect from SQL Injection attacks. You should read and learn about SQL Injection attacks because your code is vulnerable to them. Also consider using [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) which helps take care of these things for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `'` (quotes) around your `.$hosname` variable name.